# How can i fetch unmerged pull requests that i do not own?

Tags: git, github

I am using Windows and GitHub on Windows.

First I have created a repository like this:

[1[image: repo]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiL3C.png)

Then I have right clicked and clicked open git-shell:

[2[image: opening shell]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7pGx.png)

This is the master branch that I want as base:

https://github.com/FeroxRev/Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API

Then I have copy pasted this command to gitshell for clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/FeroxRev/Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API
```

[3[image: demonstration]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YNQs.png)

Ok now it is properly cloned.

**Now what I want to do is merging for example this pull request to my local repository**: https://github.com/FeroxRev/Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API/pull/53.

**What command do I need?**

This is the branch i want to merge with my local repo

https://github.com/martin-podlubny/Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API/tree/transfer-all-but-strongest-unwanted-pokemon

Comment: `git pull origin refs/pull/53/head`

Comment: @PetSerAl it throws this error fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Change directory to your cloned repo first: `cd Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API`.

Comment: @PetSerAl ty just tried and it gives this error : CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in PokemonGo/RocketAPI/Console/P
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: @user4003407 This is the right answer, unsure why it's in just a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub provides some nice documentation detailing how to merge pull requests here:

https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/

No commands required. However, make sure that after you merge on your repo, you checkout the changes on your local machine so that you are up to date with HEAD.

Comment: ty for answer but i dont see how your answer is related to my question. i mean i dont own this repository. i have cloned it locally. now as next step, how do i merge un-approved certain pull request in my local repo?

Comment: Well i dont have rights to do that. So lets say if i fork the main repo how can i do as next?

Answer (score 2):

The pull request points to a branch in a fork: you can fetch this fork.

```
git fetch https://github.com/martin-podlubny/Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API
git merge transfer-all-but-strongest-unwanted-pokemon
```

Comment: The branch name may be prefixed with the address of the repo. Use `git branch -a` to list all the branches and find the exact name

Comment: it failed with this error. not something we can merge

Comment: i just want to merge certain pull request to main branch

Comment: What branch name did you use when calling merge? What are the branches listed by `git branch -a`?

Comment: ok i guess what i want is merging this branch with my original repo : https://github.com/martin-podlubny/Pokemon-Go-Rocket-API/tree/transfer-all-but-strongest-unwanted-pokemon

Comment: You've got the idea :)
Maybe I should have formulated it like that

Comment: ok so what do i need to do for merging it with my local repo? what command?

Comment: Did you do the fetch in the beginning of my answer? Did it work? What are the branches listed by `git branch -a` in your local repo?